# Which algorithm arranges a set of jobs with each different quantities in a flat order?

Tags: ruby, math, scheduling

**Example**

Given a number of **different task types** that **need to be completed** over a **period of one month**:

```
Type  |  Number per month
--------------------------
A     |  1
B     |  5
C     |  30
D     |  15
E     |  20
--------------------------
         71
```

**Question:**

How do I generate **a flat order** (1-dimensional array) of types that ensures that

- 71 jobs are completed within one month
- the types are **spreaded as equally as possible** (ABAB instead of AABB)

**Edit:**

One Idea that came up in the comments is:

> Maybe reducing each stack of types by an amount relative to its size
>   is better than to use the absolute amount of 1. eg. A:2, B:10 results
>   in "for each A take 5 B" because B is five times larger than A.

Comment: What is the input? That ascii table or it can be an hash for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have an array of task types such as:

```
types = [[:A,1],[:B,5],[:C,6],[:D,2],[:E,3]]
```

You can first sort, and then use the greater number as reference point to build the array of tasks.

Example:

```
types = [[:A,1],[:B,5],[:C,6],[:D,2],[:E,3]]
tasks=[]; i=0

asc = types.sort {|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1] }
max = asc[types.length-1][1]

(1..max).to_a.each do |i|
    types.each {|t| tasks << t[0] if t[1] >= i}
end

puts tasks.inspect
```

produces:

```
[:A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :B, :C, :D, :E, :B, :C, :E, :B, :C, :B, :C, :C]
```

Comment: thanks for that! still, there is a problem when one type has significantly more task that need to be completed than the rest: `types = [[:A,1],[:B,2],[:C,15],[:D,2],[:E,3]]` returns `[:A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :B, :C, :D, :E, :C, :E, :C, :C, :C, :C, :C, :C, :C, :C, :C, :C, :C, :C]` ('C's are cumulating at the end)

Comment: Don't understand where the problem is. They are cumulated becouse of 15 C. Don't you want print as many tasks as indicated in the task type?

Comment: Instead of `ABCABCBCCCCCCC` the sequence `ACBCCACBCCBCCC` would be a more equal distribution. I am trying to find the most equal distribution possible, because thats the most important. Maybe reducing each stack of types by an amount relative to its size is better than to use the absolute amount of 1. eg. `A:2`, `B:10` results in "for each `A` take 5 `B`" because B is five times larger than A. What do you think?

Comment: I'm sorry, really don't understand what you mean with equal distribution. Can't improve my answer.

Comment: Instead of having lots of the same type in one place it is better to spread them over the whole list. See where the difference between `ACBCCC` and `ACCBCC` is? The latter is more euqally distributed, whereas the first has got too many C's in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Notation: You have a set X={x1,...xk} where xi needs to appear in the output ci times.

Something like this should do it:
Let C be c1+c2..+ck (71 in your example). 
Compute the stride of each item: si = C/ci.
Compute tentative locations for each item and make a (locations,item) list:
locs_i = (si,i), (2*si,i), ... (c_i*si,i)
Merge the locs_i lists lexicographically.